# Fatal Error while running helloJNI example or no output at all

Tags: java, c, gcc, java-native-interface, cygwin

I am java developer and i want to use native method with eclipse and cygwin gcc so i read instructions from [this link](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html)

and i followed all the things i generated the .class file, .c file, .h file .dll file.

i also copied hello.dll to c:\windows\system32 folder but the program not working please help me

```
    public class HelloJNI
    {
       static 
      {
    System.loadLibrary("hello");
      }

// Declare a native method sayHello() that receives nothing and returns void
private native void sayHello();

// Test Driver
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HelloJNI().sayHello(); // invoke the native method
}
}
```

And the Generated .h file using javah tool is

```
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class HelloJNI */

#ifndef _Included_HelloJNI
#define _Included_HelloJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
* Class:     HelloJNI
* Method:    sayHello
* Signature: ()V
*/
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello
(JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

And the make file i used is

```
# Define a variable for classpath
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

# Define a virtual path for .class in the bin directory
vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

all : hello.dll

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
hello.dll : HelloJNI.o
    gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -o $@ $<

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
HelloJNI.o : HelloJNI.c HelloJNI.h
    gcc -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\include\win32" -c $< -o $@

# $* matches the target filename without the extension
HelloJNI.h : HelloJNI.class
    javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*

clean :
    rm HelloJNI.h HelloJNI.o hello.dll
```

Comment: thanks Aravinth for editing my post now i understand how to create links in stackoverflow